# Refactoring code to display an alertbox (what would be a proper approach?)

Tags: swift, refactoring

I'm working on iOS project, and one thing I notice is that I'm creating an alertbox again and again whenever I need to display an error. I would like to refactor that code to remove redundancy. My question is : is creating an error handling class a proper approach to refactoring for this particular scenario? For instance, I would create a following class

```
class ErrorHandler {

     func ShowAlertBox(Title: String, Message: String, ViewController: UIViewController) {

          let alertController = UIAlertController(title: Title, message: Message), preferredStyle: .Alert)
          let doneAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Label to cancel sign-in failure."), style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(doneAction)
          ViewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

And call like this :

```
instanceofErrorHandler.ShowAlertBox("Error","Log In Error", SignInViewController)
```

Comment: I would recommend using camelCase to mark the difference between classes and variables.

Comment: Unrelated but please learn to use standard naming conventions. Variable, property, and method names should all start with lowercase letters. Class names start with uppercase letters. Following standards makes your code easier to read (and it will colorize properly on stack overflow).

Comment: @Emptyless The OP is using camelcase. The problem is starting variable and method names with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Apart from the above, your code is fine.

Comment: Duly noted. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @rmaddy there is a difference between CamelCase (also called PascalCase) and camelCase - aside from that i agree with rmaddy. Your code is fine as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there's a lot of differing opinions on how to handle this scenario and I don't see any problems with your approach. That said, the way I do it is to create an Extension called `ViewControllerUtilities` and put all of my common functions in there:

```
protocol ViewControllerUtilities {}

extension ViewControllerUtilities where Self: UIViewController {
    func showAlert(_ title: String = "Error", message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

FYI, I also have functions in there to check if the network is reachable. Then I get all this functionality simply by adding `ViewControllerUtilities` to the list of protocols that my view controller conforms to:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerUtilities {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        showAlert("Error", message: "Sorry,  had an error.")
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it's a good idea. But one question though..I've never seen the use of "where Self: UIViewController". From your example, I assume it means ViewControllerUtilities inherits from UIViewController class. Is that correct?And I assume "_ title: String" is typos?

Comment: @user30646 No, `_ title: String` is not a typo.

Comment: @rmaddy : What does it do?

Comment: The underscore just lets you omit the parameter name.

Comment: @toddg Thanks for explination!

Comment: @user30646 just came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706504/why-should-not-directly-extend-uiview-or-uiviewcontroller explaining the use of `where Self: UIViewController`. Basically, adding that `where` condition makes `ViewControllerUtilities` an opt-in extension rather than applying it to erey `UIVewController` object

Comment: @toddg Thanks a lot!